# Different Parts Of My Code Break Depending On Where Javascript Imports Are Located

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have multiple elements that use javascript. Some of it I wrote myself and some of it is code I have snatched from sites like CodePen.

I have pages extending others etc, but if I am to lay out my javascript/bootstrap imports in sequential order, this is it:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js" integrity="sha256-r/AaFHrszJtwpe+tHyNi/XCfMxYpbsRg2Uqn0x3s2zc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
[.. my code ..]
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'users/javascript.js' %}"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The problem is that certain parts of my code work and other parts dont. Ive tried moving my imports around and all it does is fixes some problems while breaking others.

I'm not really sure of the order these should be in, and as you can see some imports are above my code and some are above.

The first two imports really confuse me:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js" integrity="sha256-r/AaFHrszJtwpe+tHyNi/XCfMxYpbsRg2Uqn0x3s2zc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

It seems to me the top one is a later version and the lower one is older, yet if I remove the bottom one (3.2.1) parts of my code stop working.

Any help understanding these imports or being able to arrange them so that they don't break each other would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you importing 2 versions of jquery, one minimized and one not minimized, pick one and fix it where it breaks

Comment: When I remove one of the two my code breaks. I don't know how to fix that

Comment: Pick one, things will break, go through the javascript console and fix

Comment: Ok I'll remove one of my jquery imports and figure out how to use console to fix it. I will also remove one of my two bootstrapcdn imports, though should this code be above or below the rest of my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used another CDNs. You can try Them. The most correct order is:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
[.. my code ..]
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'users/javascript.js' %}"></script>
```

All your code should be after jQuery and Bootstrap implementation.

As @Max Carroll said use console to see errors. If you'r using Chrome - Press F12, and you will see "Console" tab. There you will see list of your errors. Clicking on the right side of a list you will open each place with error. Although you will see explanation of errors, so it's pretty easy to solve them one by one. Indeed, something might change form jQuery 3.2.1 to 3.5.0.

Comment: Thank you very much. Makes perfect sense.